# Mantaflow - creating smoke out of fluid particles

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

im trying to implement mist in my water scene, to do it im trying to use spray particles as a way to generate gas, but yet didnt find a way for it to work. I know it is possible in FLIP Fluid addon but dont know how its done either. Any suggestions will be great, thanks

Comment: why can't you use a smoke simulation?

Comment: well thats what im trying. but dont know how to use the secondary particles out of liquid simulation to be used in smoke simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Because the secondary particles are actually particle systems, it is possible to set them to render as an object. The object it renders are would be a smoke inflow object. I haven't tried this yet, so let me know if this works if you end up trying this.

Comment: well either that doesnt work or im doing something wrong. so far the only way ive found to make it is to convert the particle into mesh and make it emit short lived smoke, but that would make it painful to work with